# When combining wave functions what do the different forms signify

Tags: trigonometry

An expression like $4 \cos x + 3 \sin x$ can be written in the form:

$k \cos (x + \alpha)$

$k \sin (x - \alpha)$

$k \sin (x + \alpha)$

I do not understand what these 3 forms represent or how they apply to combining wave functions.

What I would like to know is why I would rewrite the expression in the new form/.

Comment: $\cos x+17$ cannot be written in the form $k\cos(x+a)$, so you will have to clarify your question.

Comment: As I stated, I want to understand what the 3 forms mean.  This is all new to me and I do not understand your point, so it would be nice for some patience and not to have my questions marked down by people with vastly more experience who bring up pedantic reasons.  As is often the case on this site

Comment: why can $\cos x + 17$ not be written in the form $k \cos(x + \alpha)$

Comment: Is $\cos x+17$ ever negative? What about $k\cos(x+a)$?

Comment: You know, instead of ranting, you could try to think about what I have already written in response to your question. Have you thought about $\cos x+17$ being negative, etc.? Get the chip off your shoulder, engage in the mathematics instead, and you might see that I am trying to help you, despite yourself.

Comment: Not engaging with someone who is trying to help you is also not helpful. What about $\cos x+17$, for the third time?

Comment: and for the third time, I do not understand your question.  I said that above.  It makes sense to you because you are asking it with considerably more experience than me.  I do not know the answer

Comment: cos x + 17 is a phase shift 17 units to the left.  That is all I know

Comment: OK. You know the graph of $y=\cos x$ is a wave. $y=\cos(x+a)$ is that wave but shifted to the left by the amount $a$. $y=k\cos x$ is that wave but scaled, vertically, by a factor $k$.

Comment: No, $\cos(x+17)$ is a phase shift. $\cos x+17$ is raising the graph by 17 units.

Comment: Ok, I see that now and why can that not be written in the form $k \cos(x + \alpha)$

Comment: For the fourth time, can $\cos x+17$ ever be negative? Just what do you know about $\cos x$, anyway? Do you know the biggest and smallest values it can take on? (its amplitude, in other words).

Comment: Ah, I think when you wrote "why can that not be written" you meant to write "why that can not be written". Good, we're making progress.

Comment: If x + 17 has been risen by risen by 17 units then it can never be negative but I still do not get why it cannot be written in the form $k \cos(x + a)$ when $(x + a)$ is a phase shift.  Do you mean $k$ makes this impossible?

Comment: You haven't answered my question about the largest and smallest values of $\cos x$. You have to engage with what I'm writing, or else, what's the point?

Comment: I do not know what the smallest and largest values of cos are

Comment: OK. So your real question is, what does the cosine function look like? Because if you don't understand that, you don't have any hope of understanding the things you are asking about. So, the first thing to do is to go to whatever book or notes you are learning from, and learn what the cosine function is – what values it takes, what its graph looks like (not just, "a wave", but *exactly* what it looks like). You will learn, among other things, that $\cos x$ is always between $-1$ and 1, inclusive. But, really, go read up on sine and cosine, you'll be able to ask better questions then.

Comment: @dagda1: I don't think Gerry was talking down to you. He tends to be very friendly and helpful. Don't hold him responsible for unhelpful comments by others on this site, which certainly exist. Unfortunately he's right that often people don't engage with the comments offered, and this is frustrating. His question whether $\cos x+17$ can ever be negative is quite relevant, and you simply ignored it several times in a row. That has nothing to do with your level of experience in mathematics -- even just saying "I don't know what 'negative' means" would have been better than ignoring it repeatedly.

Comment: apologies to @GerryMyerson I've had s few bad experiences on this site and thank you both for your help

Comment: @dagda1: So, to summarize the argument, $\cos x+17$ can never be negative, but all three forms you wrote can be negative, and this proves that $\cos x+17$ cannot be written in one of those forms. My question now would be, since you misunderstood $\cos x+17$ as $\cos(x+17)$, whether you really mean $a\cos x+b$ in the question, or perhaps you meant $a\cos(x+b)$?

Comment: I am not ignoring and tried to answer it but I am confused by it.  I can see that x + 17 would shift the graph 17 units higher and that would mean x would never be negative but I don't see how this applies to $k(\cos x + \alpha)$.  I don't understand how $\cos x + 17$ cannot be applied to this form or in my original question, I asked what is the point of transforming the expression into this form.

Comment: @jonki I am working through questions like this $3 \sin x + 4 \sin x$ in the form of one of those forms listed.

Comment: @dagda1: When you write $a\cos x+b$, people will usually expect $b$ to be a parameter or variable, in any case a number and not a function like $4\sin x$. If you're interested in expressions like $3\sin x+4\sin x$, you'll need to rephrase the question.

Comment: OK, I will try and rephrase the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sum of two trigonometric functions is more complicated than a shifted and scaled trigonometric function, in the sense that it involves the variable twice instead of once. For instance, it would be hard to solve

$$
4\cos x+3\sin x=1
$$

for $x$ without first combining the two trigonometric functions, since it's not straightforward to separate the two occurrences of $x$. By contrast, once you have

$$
4\cos x+3\sin x=5\sin\left(x+\arctan\frac43\right)\;,
$$

solving the equation is merely a matter of reversing all the operations:

$$
5\sin\left(x+\arctan\frac43\right)=1\\
\sin\left(x+\arctan\frac43\right)=\frac15\\
x+\arctan\frac43=\arcsin\frac15\\
x=\arcsin\frac15-\arctan\frac43\
$$

(This is only one specific solution, the one picked out by $\arcsin$; any equation of the form $\sin x=c$ has infinitely many solutions for $x$ if it has any at all.)